# Issues with request from Angular 16 to Rest API with token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, angular16

When making a request from Angular 16 to a Java REST API, I'm receiving the token in the header as null. However, if I make the request from POSTMAN, it works perfectly.

I have a frontend with Angular and a backend with Java. The Java part is secured with Spring Security, OAuth2, and JWT. Once I perform the login and retrieve the token in Angular, I attempt to fetch the list of users by sending the token in the request header. Upon checking in Java, I consistently find that the token is coming in as null. Below are the Angular reques

```
 private urlEndPointUsuarios: string = 'http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public router: Router,
    public authService: AuthService) { }

  private agregarAuthorizationHeader() {
     let token = this.authService.token;
     if (token != null) {
      this.httpHeaders = this.httpHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
       return this.httpHeaders;
     }
     return this.httpHeaders;
  }

  getUsuarios(): Observable<Usuario[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.urlEndPointUsuarios, { headers: this.agregarAuthorizationHeader()}).pipe(
      map(response => response as Usuario[])
    )
  }
```

Next, my Java method that receives the request and checks the token is as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String token = null;
        String username = null;
        
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            token = authHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtService.extractUsername(token);
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtService.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

On the other hand, if I make the request from Postman with the token, it works perfectly. I can see how I receive the token in Java and I can view the list of users in Postman. I would appreciate some help with this. Thank you.

Comment: why have you written a custom filter? using a JWT as a session like you are doing is bad practice. JWTs are not meant to be handed out to browsers. They are meant to be used as short lived tokens between microservices. There is a reason to why this type of implementation does not exist in spring security. Please google why jwts should not be used as session tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a library for Angular OAuth2 "public" clients like [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client), you'd have less problems. It properly handles OAuth2 flows, does silent tokens refreshing and automatically authorises requests matching host and path you configure (and does it correctly: Spring will find the token).

However, [it is now recommended by Spring Security team to use only "confidential" clients](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), which means that your Angular app should be authorized with session cookies on an OAuth2 client running on your server (instead of being authorized with Bearer tokens to query OAuth2 resource servers).

So two options:

- change your backend conf from OAuth2 resource server to OAuth2 client with login (or turn it into something not OAuth2 at all: if you don't use SSO, then maybe Form login is an option to consider)
- introduce a Backend For Frontend (BFF) between Angular and resource server(s) configured as an OAuth2 client and bridging from session authorization to Bearer token one. `spring-cloud-gateway` can easily be used for that purpose with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `TokenRelay=` filter. I wrote [a tutorial for that](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).